# MySQL Query Times out - Need to speed it up

Tags: mysql, sql

I whipped up a query here that does something particular with retrieving results that do not match the join (as suggested by this SO question).

```
SELECT cf.f_id
FROM comments_following AS cf
INNER JOIN comments AS c ON cf.c_id = c.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM follows WHERE f_id = cf.f_id
)
```

Any ideas on how to speed this up? There are anywhere from 30k-200k rows it's looking through and appears to be using indexes, but the query times out.

EXPLAIN/DESCRIBE Info:

```
1   PRIMARY c   ALL PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    39119   
1   PRIMARY cf  ref c_id, c_id_2    c_id    8   ...c.id 11  Using where; Using index
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  following   index   NULL    PRIMARY 8   NULL    35612   Using where; Using index
```

Comment: add keyword "DESCRIBE" infront of it to get an analyse from the database it self, and post the result to get us to explain it for you

Comment: What does the [execution plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) have to say about your query ?

Comment: Updated w/ query info.

Comment: Whats the purpose of the query, why joining the table comments? may be that im not used to inner joins, but if it was a left join, ther would be no need to join the comment table

Comment: Good question. There is a need because there's an ID that needs to be brought over from the other table that doesn't exist in the two current tables. Without it, an index will not be used. Also, this query is actually an INSERT query (I removed for the sake of solving the select, which is the slow part). INSERT IGNORE INTO table (..., ..., ...) SELECT ...

Comment: can you do an explain/describe with an left join on comments, insted of a inner join?

Comment: should we continue in a chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31008/room-for-puggan-se-and-stwhite so we not fill up this question with testdata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `comments` table isn't used explicitly in the query.  Is it being used for filtering?  If not, try:

```
SELECT cf.f_id
FROM comments_following cf
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM follows WHERE follows.f_id = cf.f_id
)
```

By the way, if this generates a syntax error (because follows.f_id does not exist), then that is the problem.  In that case, you would think you have a correlated subquery, but there is not really one.

Or the `left outer join` version:

```
SELECT cf.f_id
FROM comments_following cf left outer join
     follows f
     on f.f_id = cf.f_id
where f.f_id is null
```

Having an index on `follows(f_id)` should make both these versions run faster.

Answer (score 1):

LEFT JOIN sometimes is faster then WHERE NOT EXISTS subquerys, try:

```
SELECT cf.f_id
FROM comments_following AS cf
INNER JOIN comments AS c ON cf.c_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN follows AS f ON f.f_id = cf.f_id
WHERE f.f_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Just tried that but the query still times out (takes over a minute)... I updated the original question w/ query explain info.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem was to place a second index on `follows.f_id`.